# Looking for filecopy software that I can provide a file list

Tags: file-synchronization

I have a use case involving copying 1000's of files from various locations on the network to a single consolidated location. I am struggling to find software that will allow me to provide a file list, and the software copy those files. This will be used by end-users and each user will have a unique file list, so I would ideally like something with a GUI that accepts a file list in TXT, CSV, XML or XSLX format.

All of the software I've reviewed so that seem to only allow filtering of files, rather than allowing us to explicitly provide a file list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution using [TeraCopy Pro](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy).

You can use this command line to load the list which opens TeraCopy with the file list loaded.

```
TeraCopy.exe AddList *"C:\YourPath\filelist.txt"
```

They will add an option to import file lists in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any GUI-based Zip Application has an "import filelist" option, but I think there should be one.

My idea is: On Linux, you could use the classic "zip" Command Line Tool together with its `-@` option to copy all files listed in a Textfile into a zip file, then sync that.

From the manual (`man zip`):

```
       -@ file lists.  If a file list is specified as -@ [Not on MacOS], zip takes the list 
          of input files from standard input instead of from the command line.
          For  example,

              zip -@ foo

       will store the files listed one per line on stdin in foo.zip.
```

You could then store the zip file locally, and/or you could transfer the zip file to your backup server, unzip it there and throw away the zip file.

Various alternatives to this basic idea are possible : using different utilities than zip (e.g. "tar", "gzip")...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like for each user to be able to list a selection of his/her files, stored somewhere/anywhere, and then copy them collectively to some specific destination folder.

I am thinking of [XYplorer](https://www.xyplorer.com/), a (much) better File Manager than the one included with Windows. With XYplorer, a user can tag and/or label individual files. Then all it would need is to list the tagged files (simple menu option), mark them (e.g. like Ctrl-A), and then copy/move them to the desired target folder.

If needed (and willing to), this can be scripted/automated internally in the software.

**Edit:** The only other thing I can think of is to create a small script (e.g. Python) that takes a textfile as parameter and copies the files to a pre-configured target folder. Assumes that the source file names are listed with their full path.